# How to maximize windows to the middle monitor with three monitors

Tags: unity, ati, monitor

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and most things are running smoothly. I've managed to set up my three monitors using ATI's Catalyst Control Center.

However, I run into problems when I try to maximize windows to my middle monitor - namely, it seems impossible. **Modifying the realtive positions of the monitors using CCC seems to temporarily fix the problem, but the "solution" does not persist over restarts.**

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the display settings and turn on the "Sticky Edges" option and it should cause your mouse to stick to the edge before moving to the next monitor thus allowing for the function to work. It is quite buggy doing this as sometimes your mouse won't go to the next monitor and just well sticks. You can also try turning on the Xinerama (or something like that) and see if that will do it for you. Your last option is to reconfigure your "Monitor's Emulated Position". Meaning in the "X" settings you should be able to drag and drop monitor 1,2, or 3 in the middle,left, or right side. Let me know what else is going on and if you can provide a screenshot I may be able to further assist. (Screenshot of your ATI settings)

Comment: Sticky Edges isn't relevant - even using the maximize hotkey (Ctrl + Alt + 5) I am unable to maximize the window. I have already tried repositioning the emulated position, but that only fixes until a restart, regardless of what position I place the monitor in.

Comment: Can you go to chat? General Ubuntu room

Comment: The problem seems to have spontaneously reduced itself to one application - Google Chrome. I am marking this answer as accepted because it seems like it would cover a large number of possible problems, as described by my question.

Comment: Thanks. Try using Chromium its the same thing as Chrome just optimized for linux